# How to move an edge loop along the normals of each edge?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I've got a bit of a problem where I want to move an edge loop along the normals of each edge. If I have gaps between the selected vertices, it works fine - as shown below.

[image: 1st image]

But I want to move the whole edge loop, not every second vertex/edge. When I have individual origins selected and normal orientation and I press G then Z Z, it seems to move along an average normal for the whole edge loop, as shown below.

[image: 2nd image]

Sorry if I haven't explained this well.

Comment: try using Alt+S

Comment: I've put that in an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Shrink/Fatten** tool is what you are looking for. Select your vertices then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. You might find it useful to activate **Even Thickness** by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>.